# Issue with Codeigniter sessions on Iphone

Tags: php, iphone, codeigniter, session, session-cookies

My authentication uses CI sessions and works fine everywhere that I have checked. I just noticed that on the iPhone I can only login if I clear all cookies and data from the iPhone(safari) browser. Ipad is fine doesn't have this issue.

Are the cookies being corrupted? has anyone come across this. I would like to be able to continue using CI sessions. I have toggled encrypting the cookie as someone suggested that. Didn't work.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: How many iPhones did you try it on? Have you tried resetting a iPhone you tested it on? Does it happen in the Chrome browser (available in the App Store) as well?

Comment: @Geert: Thanks for the idea to try Chrome. Chrome works fine on the iphone. I have only tested this version of my application on the iphone 5. So maybe it is just a safari bug on the iphone.

Comment: Try using a different iPhone, maybe it works just fine on there?

Answer (score 0):

Having looked around it appears that the cause is safari on the iphone caching Ajax requests.
Nothing to do with sessions at all.
Adding a timestamp to my ajax request solved my issue.

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
```

Off I go through all my js files looking for $.ajax
:)