# session variable is not being saved on the iphone

Tags: php, iphone, ajax, codeigniter, mobile-safari

**UPDATE:**

I was using .htaccess to redirect users to a specific folder (/var/www/html/test) that had all these files when they accessed my website.
The .htaccess looked like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (?!^test(/.*|)$)^(.*)$ /test/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I moved all the files to /var/www/html  and commented the .htaccess lines.. The sessions on iphone started working... I have no idea why.. Is there a way to fix that with .htaccess?

**---- End Of Update -----**

I have an ajax function that calls a user login function and if the user/password are correct, it logs in the user. It works on the desktop, laptop, samsung s3 phones but NOT on the IPHONE! The `$this->session->set_userdata('current_email', $email);` seem not to set the session on the IPHONE therefore redirecting user back to login page. I am guessing maybe that's because iphone safari cookies are disabled automatically or something like that. What's the best way to go around this so it works on the phone?

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                url: site_url+"/user/login/"+email,
                type: "post",
                data: 'password='+password+'&email='+email,
                success: function(response){    
                    if(response == "success"){
                      window.location.href = site_url+"/user/invites";
                    }else{
                      alert("Password is not valid");
                    }   
                },  
                error: function(){
                }   
            });
```

/user/login php codeigniter function

```
public function login($email)
        {

                $password = $this->input->post('password');

                if($email != NULL){

                        $this->load->helper('string');
                        $this->load->model('user_model');
                        $this->load->library('session');

                        $user_status = $this->user_model->check_status($email, $password);

                        if (is_array($user_status) && $user_status['is_active']) {

                                $this->session->set_userdata('current_email', $email);
                                $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user_status['id']);
                                $this->session->set_userdata('unique_id', $user_status['unique_id']);
                                $this->session->set_userdata('is_active', 1);

                                echo "success"; die();
                        }

                } die();

        }
```

/user/invites

```
 public function invites($unique_id = NULL)
        {

                if($this->session->userdata('current_email') != FALSE){

                        $data['unique_id'] = $this->session->userdata('unique_id');
                        $data['current_email'] = $this->session->userdata('current_email');

                        if($data['unique_id']){

                                $data['invited_users'] = $this->user_model->get_invited_users($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

                                $data['user_details'] = $this->user_model->get_user_details($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

                        $this->template->write_view('header', 'templates/header2', $data);
                        $this->template->write_view('content', 'invites', $data);

                        // Render the template
                        $this->template->render();

                }else{ 
                        redirect('welcome/index/1','refresh');
                }
```

Comment: It could be a caching problem, see my update answer for a possible approach

Comment: Have you tried using native php sessions `$_SESSION['current_email'] =  $email` instead of codeigniters approach?

Comment: @CodeCrack do you use an encryption key for session? can you post your **config.php** about session pls?

Comment: try setting sess_match_useragent to false in your config, see if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest an alternative: use the database as session handler.

You just need to enable it in the application/config/config.php file:

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

You need a table to store the saved sessions, the manual suggests using this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Other than this, you don't need to do anything, all the needed queries are handled by CI automatically, no change to be done in your actual code.

**UPDATE:**

A search on google led me to [this CI forum thread](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/225304/#1032914) (and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685171/issue-with-codeigniter-sessions-on-iphone)). The cause might be safari caching the AJAX request, so you need to add a timestamp to the url and the issue should be resolved. Example:

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();    
$.ajax({
     url: site_url+"/user/login/"+email+"?"+timestamp, // Or use '/' instead of '?'
```

Comment: They are set. Just not on the iPhone! I am trying to figure out a way around it without db sessions.

Comment: I tried that before but that didn't work. I also saw that solution before but I am not sure that applies to my case.

Comment: I even tried the DB session solution and the iphone still redirects to main page because it can't detect the email

Comment: Did you try testing this on more than 1 iPhone to ensure that its not just that single phone that has the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is the ajax call sent to an external domain ?

If so, this might have something to do with security issues. 
See: http://drupal.org/node/918194

I have only dealt with this problem in IE, I don't know if this could happen on iOS.

So try adding the following on the ajax receiving side script:

```
<?php
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'); 
?>
```

Note: make sure this header is put on all necessary pages and it occurs at the very beginning of your script.