# Codeigniter login using session not working in iPad and other mobile browsers

Tags: codeigniter

I am able to get login and print session in the function but when i click on any other function my session get lost and it redirect me back to index page as each function is having session set constraint. Below written is the code:

```
$session = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
redirect('user/user_dashboard');
```

and when i print session over there it prints and after removing die it lost.

Comment: You need to deliver more information. What exactly is not working? Any errors? How is your session coded. We can't answer this question just out of nowhere

Comment: @PatrickManser: please review the query now.

Comment: Are you using any JavaScrip? AJAX maybe?

Comment: Oh and which browser did you use on the mobile devices?

Comment: Its working fine in ipda1 but its not working in ipad 2 with ios 7.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the browser you're testing for Safari? I found a lot of reports that this is a common problem with Safari on iPad or iPhone, but also with Internet Explorer, which I've solved in the past.

When I encountered this in the past on Internet Explorer, I fixed it by setting the following option in config.php:

```
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

Apparently, the problem is caused by the fact that the session_id() is regenerated every time a user loads any page. By not checking for the useragent any more, apparently, CodeIgniter's native session class no longer performs that particular check-up.

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: That was my though aswell, because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685171/issue-with-codeigniter-sessions-on-iphone

Comment: Its working fine in ipda1 but its not working in ipad 2 with ios 7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Use session in database instead of files. First create table in your database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
`id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
`data` blob NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

Then add following lines in your config file

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```